# How to pass the handler function to the another screen in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have problem passing the handler function to the second screen it says that HandleChangeFirstName is not a function or undefined.

Question: Is it possible to update the parent state from the second screen?

Goal: To update the state on the first screen

First Screen Code:

```
    const HandleChangeFirstName = (e, i) => {
        let newArr = [...BookingData];
        newArr[i]['dest_firstname'] = e;
        setBookingData(newArr);
    }

    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('BookingDestination', {
        dest_data: BookingData[i],
        HandleChangeFirstName:HandleChangeFirstName
    })}>
        <Icon
            as={IconAnt}
            name={"edit"}
            size={5}
            color={'#FF403D'}
            mr="3"
        />
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Second Screen Code:

```
const { dest_data, HandleChangeFirstName } = route.params;

<Text p="1" fontWeight="500" fontSize="13">First Name</Text>
<TextBox
    onChangeText={(e) => HandleChangeFirstName(e, 0)}
    value={dest_data?.dest_firstname}
    name="firstname"
    placeholder="First Name"
    size="lg"
    isDisabled={dest_data?.isSearchSelected ? true : false}
    fontSize="12"
    placeholderColor="#000"
    fontWeight="300"
    icon="user"
    iconColor="#1E89D6"
>
</TextBox>
```

Error:

[image: Error]

Comment: i dont think so its possible with the code you have shared. state management is the only thing that i can suggest you for this. dispatch your state on the onChangeText and receive it on your desired screen

Comment: @ShoyebMemon yah thanks for your suggestion, I know only state management can help for this problem. Let's see if there someone know if this one can possible. Again Thank you.